# Problem calling (jax-ws) web service from within JBoss

Tags: jboss, jax-ws

I am trying to connect to a web service via a VPN from my server.  I can connect to the wsdl and send a soap request using Curl (it gets a valid response too).  The code I am using is able to connect to the web service when installed on another server, but for some reason does not seem to connect from within JBoss on this server.  There is very little in the logs that appears to be of any help.  I am also able to ping the server.

This is what it says in the logs..... (the wsdl shown in the log is correct, I have replaced it with "http://:/<>/?wsdl", also the service in line 1 shows the correct value.... Can anyone suggest what the issue may be?

14:34:07,805 DEBUG [org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSWebServiceMetaDataBuilder] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) START buildMetaData: [service={http:
///}]

14:34:07,810 DEBUG [org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDLDefinitionsFactory] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-1) parse: http://:/<>/?wsdl

14:34:07,892 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6) pipeline process for message: 
header: [  ]

14:34:07,892 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6) executing processor 0 org.jbos
s.soa.esb.listeners.message.OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor@243cc381 header: [  ]

14:35:07,881 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) pipeline process for message: 
header: [  ]

14:35:07,881 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4) executing processor 0 org.jbos
s.soa.esb.listeners.message.OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor@243cc381 header: [  ]

14:35:17,991 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3) pipeline process for message: 
header: [  ]

14:35:17,991 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3) executing processor 0 org.jbos
s.soa.esb.actions.MessageRedeliverer@456bf9ce header: [  ]

14:35:18,024 DEBUG [org.jboss.internal.soa.esb.persistence.format.db.DBMessageStoreImpl] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3) retrieved 0 RDLVR messa
ges

14:35:39,060 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] (Thread-5) Periodic recovery - first pass

14:35:39,060 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] (Thread-5) StatusModule: first pass

14:35:39,060 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.txoj.logging.txojLoggerI18N] (Thread-5) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule_3] - TORecovery
Module - first pass

14:35:39,060 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-5) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.info.firstpass] Local XARecoveryModule
 - first pass

14:35:49,070 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] (Thread-5) Periodic recovery - second pass

14:35:49,070 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] (Thread-5) AtomicActionRecoveryModule: Second pass

14:35:49,070 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.txoj.logging.txojLoggerI18N] (Thread-5) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule_6] - TORecovery
Module - second pass

14:35:49,070 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-5) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.info.secondpass] Local XARecoveryModul
e - second pass

14:36:07,900 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3) pipeline process for message: 
header: [  ]

14:36:07,900 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3) executing processor 0 org.jbos
s.soa.esb.listeners.message.OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor@243cc381 header: [  ]

14:37:07,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5) pipeline process for message: 
header: [  ]

14:37:07,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5) executing processor 0 org.jbos
s.soa.esb.listeners.message.OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor@243cc381 header: [  ]

14:37:43,917 DEBUG [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.IdleRemover] (IdleRemover) run: IdleRemover notifying pools, interval: 450000

14:37:49,077 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] (Thread-5) Periodic recovery - first pass

14:37:49,077 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] (Thread-5) StatusModule: first pass

14:37:49,077 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.txoj.logging.txojLoggerI18N] (Thread-5) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule_3] - TORecovery
Module - first pass

14:37:49,077 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-5) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.info.firstpass] Local XARecoveryModule
 - first pass

14:37:59,087 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] (Thread-5) Periodic recovery - second pass

14:37:59,087 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] (Thread-5) AtomicActionRecoveryModule: Second pass

14:37:59,087 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.txoj.logging.txojLoggerI18N] (Thread-5) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule_6] - TORecovery
Module - second pass

14:37:59,087 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N] (Thread-5) [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.info.secondpass] Local XARecoveryModul
e - second pass

14:38:07,897 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8) pipeline process for message: 
header: [  ]

14:38:07,897 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8) executing processor 0 org.jbos
s.soa.esb.listeners.message.OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor@243cc381 header: [  ]

14:39:07,672 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (Thread-3) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction_58] - Abort of action i
d a01023b:9784:4b02b364:125 invoked while multiple threads active within it.

14:39:07,672 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N] (Thread-3) [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.CheckedAction_2] - CheckedAction::c
heck - atomic action a01023b:9784:4b02b364:125 aborting with 1 threads active!

14:39:07,885 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) pipeline process for message: 
header: [  ]

14:39:07,885 DEBUG [org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.ActionProcessingPipeline] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) executing processor 0 org.jbos
s.soa.esb.listeners.message.OverriddenActionLifecycleProcessor@243cc381 header: [  ]

Answer (score 0):

You said you can ping the server from your client, but can you also connect to the web port on your server?  For example, open up a command window or shell prompt on your client machine and type 
`telnet <server> <port>`.

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect via telnet to port 8180 (which is the port specified in the wsdl)